# What is the length of $AB$

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to solve this question. What is the length of $AB$? All we know is that the area of the shaded area is $2\pi$

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Could you solve the problem if $\overline{AB}$ were a diameter?

Comment: To expand-upon my comment ... *Assuming* this is a well-posed question with an unambiguous answer, the lack of specificity about the location of $\overline{AB}$ means that you should get the same answer *regardless* of the location of $\overline{AB}$; taking the segment to be a diameter makes finding that common answer fairly straightforward. (The famous [Napkin-Ring Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napkin_ring_problem) invites the same problem-solving approach.) As answers show, you can also solve the problem by more general means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me call the circles $C_1,C_2,C_3$ with $C_1$ being the largest, and $C_3$ being the smallest. The area of $C_i$ is $A_{C_i}=\pi r_i^2$ for $i=1,2,3$. We know $A_{C_1}-A_{C_2}-A_{C_3}=\pi r_1^2-\pi r_2^2-\pi r_3^2=2\pi$, i.e. $r_1^2-r_2^2-r_3^2=2$ or
$$r_2^2=r_1^2-r_3^2-2\quad(1)$$

and

$$r_1=r_2+r_3\quad\Rightarrow \quad r_2^2=(r_1-r_3)^2\quad(2)$$

Due to the [geometric mean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean_theorem) we have $\frac{1}{2}AB=\sqrt{d_2\cdot d_3}=\sqrt{4r_2\cdot r_3}=2\sqrt{r_2r_3}$ or

$$AB=4\sqrt{r_2r_3}.\quad(3)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sorry if i'm missing something but why is r1=r2+r3 ?

Comment: $d_i=\frac{1}{2}r_i$ and $d_2+d_3=d_1$ and therefore $r_1=r_2+r_3.$ The reason is: the two smaller circles fit perfectly in the biggest.

Comment: Thanks! To be able to solve it, all i wanted is r1 = r2+r3. The problem is that it didn't seem like that to me and using simple algebra you can actually prove it.

Answer (score 3):

Referring to the diagram:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

$$\pi(y+2x)^2-\pi(x+y)^2-\pi x^2=2\pi \Rightarrow x(x+y)=1;\\
z^2=(y+2x)^2-y^2=4x(x+y)=4 \Rightarrow z=2;\\
AB=2z=4.$$

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck!